# How to Specify Drive Letter on Remote Server for Copy or XCopy Command

Tags: batch-file, copy, command, command-line-interface, xcopy

I am trying to write a batch file, so my support team can copy a file to a specified server whenever needed. The problem is that the target folder on the remote server is on a different partition than C. How can i specify another drive letter on this remote system?

```
copy \\team\folder\file.txt \\remote\$X Drive$\folder\file.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything like `\\remote\X\...` or `\\remote\X$\...`?

Comment: Have you tried `$x` or `x$`? I'm not on a Windows box at the moment, but I recall using a dollar sign in the past to do something similar to what you're asking.

Comment: What do you see in the location bar in Windows Explorer when you look at that remote folder?

Comment: i have tried `\\remote\X\ --- \\remote\X$\ --- \\remote\$X\` neither have worked. this drive letter is a partition on the remote server, if that helps. it's Windows Server 2003, so other than the 'name' of the partition, which i've also tried to use, I don't see an actual path name in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You does not specify any letter in the remote system. You specify the name given to the shared resource. See if the required drive is being shared and under what name, and use this name.

Comment: the drive is a partition on a local disk on the remote computer. it is not shared. the above command works just fine on the C drive, without specification, but i'm wondering how do i specify the other partition?

Comment: If the folder or drive is not shared then in normal use you cannot access it.

Comment: @btgream:  By default, there are administrative shares defined over the root directory of each partition, the usual C$, D$, ... These share names are the "letters" you are referencing. BUT they are share names. And they can be removed or profiled changing rights. As foxidrive says, if no share, no access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powershell to do this.

```
Copy-Item "\\team\folder\file.txt" "\\remote\X$\folder\"
```

In this solution, the remote folder in X must exist.

If you want to copy a whole folder with its contents:

```
Copy-Item "\\team\folder\" "\\remote\X$\folder\" -Recurse
```